# How to import data from Excel file to Teradata table using BTEQ scripts?

Tags: excel, import, teradata

I was able to do fill tables with data from Excel file or text files using GUI utility Teradata Sql assistant. But now I have a requirement to import data into teradata tables from excel file using a bteq script. I have been trying to do that using

.IMPORT REPORT

.IMPORT DATA

.IMPORT VARTEXT and I have tried other things also, but of no use. I have referred to some answers in teradataforum and googled for the same but my script is not working. Please help me with a script which will import data from excel file or atleast text file using BTEQ script.My script is as follows...

```
.LOGON XXXX/XXXXXX,XXXX
.import data FILE = D:\XX\XXXX.xls ;
.QUIET ON 
.REPEAT * 
USING COL1  (CHAR(1))
     ,COL2  (CHAR(1))
     ,COL3 (VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO DATABASE.TABLE
    ( COL1
     ,COL2
     ,COL3)
VALUES ( :COL1
        ,:COL2
        ,:COL3);
.QUIT
```

**EDIT:**

Till now I came this long. I have successfully loaded data from comma separated text file using the following code. But how to do it in Excel?

```
.LOGON xxxx/xxxx,xxxx
.IMPORT VARTEXT ',' FILE=xxxxx.TXT;
.QUIET ON 
.REPEAT * 
USING 
(   col1 VARCHAR(2)
    ,col2 VARCHAR(1)
    ,col3 VARCHAR(60)
)        
INSERT INTO database.table
    ( col1
     ,col2
     ,col3)
VALUES ( :col1
    ,:col2
    ,:col3);
.QUIT
```

Sample comma separated text file being

```
1,B,status1
2,B,status2
3,B,status3
```

---

etc.
Please help me if possible to load the same with Excel file.

Comment: Looks like I need to believe in myself and use trial and error method until I get it... haa.... Please help if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible - Excel is a binary format.  You have to save it as a comma-separated values file (.CSV) from Excel.  You might also be able to come up with some convoluted solution using an Access database that links to the Teradata table and the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Atlast somebody from teradata's unknown land somebody responded. I will definitely look into the solution you proposed. But one thing is we can import data from excel file into teradata table using Teradata SQL assistant. Then why can't we use BTEQ for similar purpose? If it is really not possible then I will leave it. Once again thanks.

Comment: You can't import data from an xls file in SQL Assistant. You can only save your answerset as one. I think the reason SQL Assistant even knows about Excel is tha it is a Windows app whereas BTEQ is a more generic lower level cross-platform command-line app.